# Django. Генерация html sitemap

Tags: django, sitemap

Сайтмап в xml сгенерировал по этому руководству https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/contrib/sitemaps/ , однако, там нет указаний на создание html сайтмапа. Есть у джанго такой механизм генерации для html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. (правда я даже предположить не могу зачем вам это)

Взгляните на определение url'а sitemap:

```
views.sitemap(request, sitemaps, section=None, template_name='sitemap.xml', content_type='application/xml')
```

Туда можно передать шаблон в качестве template_name и генерируемый content_type. Соответственно вам нужно написать свой шаблон, например, html_sitemam.html на основе [sitemap.xml из django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.7/django/contrib/sitemaps/templates/sitemap.xml)

Далее необходимо добавить в urls.py примерно следующее

```
[
    # ...
    url(r'^sitemap\.html$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps, 'template_name': 'html_sitemap.html', 'content_type': 'text/html'})
]
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Карту сайта для посетителей, для этой цели

Comment: Для чего вводится последний аргумент функции - html_sitemap?

Comment: Затрудняюсь ответить, не используйте этот параметр, видимо я неправильно отредактировал код, когда копировал из репозитория. Ответ исправил

Comment: И фигурную скобку нужно перенести (передаем словарь kwargs), урл будет такой url(r'^sitemap\.html$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps, 'template_name': 'html_sitemap.html', 'content_type': 'text/html'}),

Comment: @while1pass Точно, точно я отвечая на работе, как-то упустил этот момент